# How to reference 2 ArrayAdapters separately

Tags: android

I've been working on understanding ArrayAdapters for the past 2 days, but can't seem to get them down entirely.

The following code is functional as is.

```
    private void initAdapter(ArrayList<String> aL) {


    for (String s : aL) {
        aL.add(s);
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, aL) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;

        if (null == convertView) {
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        } else {
        row = convertView;
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(getItem(position));

        return row;
        }
       });
}
```

I am trying to make it into a method where I can use ArrayAdapter on multiple Arrays and put them into separate ListViews.
When I try modifying the method to

```
private void initAdapter(ArrayList<String> aL, ListView L) {
```

and

```
L.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this. R.layout.list_item, aL) {
```

I get an error at compile.
Also, why is it that you don't have to specify a ListView for your first ArrayAdapter. Does it just automatically reference anything with the id 'list'?

I am quite confused and stuck on this and would be very grateful for a well-explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code is part of an [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html). In that case the method `setListAdapter()` automatically refers to the list by id `android.R.id.list`. For what is going on with the adapter, a stack trace from logcat would be needed to see what error does occur there.